# Loading an assembly from any version

Tags: c#, assemblies, version, assemblyversions

I'm referencing a signed assembly. In runtime it is ok for me to work with any version of that assembly, not just the one I compiled to.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you change the title of the question appropriately, such that it becomes somewhat easy for people to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not going to work.  The CLR will verify the assembly version number, expecting to get the one that your main program was compiled against.  You would have to use the [`<bindingRedirect>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in the app.config file to convince it that a different version is okay.

That's a slippery slope.  Consider only changing the [AssemblyVersion] attribute if the public interface of the assembly changed and requires clients to be recompiled.  Now the exception you'll get is one that identifies a real problem.  This is another kind of slippery slope, but one you'll have much more control over.

For comparison, this is the way all the base assemblies in the .NET framework work.  There have been *many* revisions of them between .NET 2.0 RTM and 3.5 SP1, including many invisible hotfixes.  But the [AssemblyVersion] is still 2.0.0.0, Microsoft only modifies the [AssemblyFileVersion].

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE, make sure "Specific Version" is set to false against the reference, or add `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` to the reference in the csproj.

Comment: @Marc: How will the runtime determine which assembly (out of multiple versions) to load? (I am assuming a signed assembly is placed in GAC).

Comment: @Marc: I searched on the question I asked you above & it seems the runtime will pick the latest version of the assembly. Is that right?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I have no idea; I almost never use GAC

Comment: @Yaron Naveh - should do. In fact, IIRC it can't *reliably* work as "only use the specific version" **unless** it is signed.